# Organizing Doxygen index list differently/properly

Tags: c, doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I'm trying to generate properly organized Doxygen documentation for a work project. The issue I'm having is related to the image below:

[image: module detail list]

Everything under the "State Machine" tab are the data structures, macros, typedefs, etc. in that order that belong to the module in different files. Is there any way to get rid of the detailed listing and instead have it grouped as:

- State Machine

  - Data Structures

    - mdlSM_INV
    - mdlSM...
  - Macros

    - mdlSM_cnf...

So on and so forth?

OR to just get rid of the whole list i.e. just have the name of the module and not have it expand into anything else?

I'm working with Doxywizard and Doxygen version 1.8.18 that I cannot update (at the moment at least) as I don't have admin rights on the computer. The project is in embedded C, written in Code Composer Studio.

EDIT: The current file contents looks something like this:

```
/*! \addtogroup mdlStatemachine State Machine
 *@brief  Implement state machine
 *
 *@{
 */
 
#include ...

// MACROS
#define mdlSM_cnf_TICKS_PER_MS
#define mdlSM_cnf_SAMPLE_INTERVAL
#define ...


// TYPEDEFS
/*!@brief
 * ...
 */
typedef enum mdlSM_cnf_States
{
    ...
    ...
}mdlSM_cnf_States_t;


/*!@brief
 * ...
 */
typedef struct mdlSM_INV
{
    ...
}mdlSM_INV_t;


// FUNCTIONS
/*!@brief  ...
 *
 */
void SM_init(SM *me, SMState state)
{
    ...
}

// END OF FILE
/*! @}*/
```

The idea is to put entire files in the modules and not every function etc. individually.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the possibilities of the doxygen layout file, see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout

Comment: So I'm looking at that section and I generated the xml file from doxygen to have a starter file. But I'm afraid it didn't really help me. I tried modifying some sections and regenerating the documentation but nothing noticeably changed.. @albert

Comment: What did you change? Can you give a small example source file that shows the problem you have?

Comment: Is it correct you have a number of `...group` commands in your code that cause these entries?

Comment: I'll try to add a short example of the source file. But in the meantime, this module consists of 7 files. There is a "\addtogroup mdlStatemachine State Machine" command at the start of each file but is not repeated within the files anywhere.

Comment: I think you might also have a `\{` just beneath the `\addtogroup`  and at the end of the file a `\}` so all things in between are added to the group (modules). Not sure about the use case but maybe you have to remove the `\addtogroup` or refine the selection a bit by  excluding some parts

Comment: @albert I updated my question with details on how the files are structured. This is very generic, not every file has all these types of data. The screenshot of the Doxygen documentation combines data types from all files in this module and lists them alphabetically as part of the index..

Comment: I did some experiments and as far as I can see it is currently not possible to remove individual parts from the "Modules".

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help anyway. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it and close the question..